# asp.net radiobuttonlist will not selectindex

Tags: c#, asp.net, radiobuttonlist, selectedindex

I have a radio button list...

```
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblCollectOptions" runat="server" CssClass="radiolist">
            <asp:ListItem Value="Collect" Text="Collect from this address"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="DropOff" Text="Drop off at Depot (UK only)"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I also have a link button on the page to "enter address manually" which I want to set the radio button to "Collect" value.

I tried...

```
rblCollectOptions.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

and

```
rblCollectOptions.Items[0].Selected = true;
```

both work if no option is already selected, but if I manually set the radio button to another option, or set a default selection, the link button does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [ClearSelection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.clearselection.aspx) or set `SelectedIndex = -1` before you set the selected item.

```
rblCollectOptions.ClearSelection();
```

or

```
rblCollectOptions.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Comment: Perfect! thanks, I didn't think of this I thought it would have worked the same way as a `dropdownlist`.